# Hdf5 file reading speed slowing down suddenly

Tags: python, pytorch, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to iterate through a hdf5 file. The file consists of a series of 'timestamps', and for each one there is a variable number of 'players', from which I want to obtain data. The file is quite big though, there are over 17k timestamps, and I observe that the time taken in getting 'players = list(data[timestamp].keys())' suddenly increases a lot after some hundred iterations, from about 0.0005 second to about 0.05.

```
        with h5py.File(self.hdf5file, "r") as f:
            data = f['data']
            timestamps = list(data.keys())
            for timestamp in timestamps:
                start_time = time.time()
                players = list(data[timestamp].keys())
                end_time = time.time()
                print(end_time - start_time)
```

I have no idea what might be happening and how to work around it.

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion that *may* help. Assuming you have plenty of memory to play with try: *with h5py.File(self.hdf5file, driver='core') as f:*

Comment: @JCaesar thanks for the comment. Would you mind explaining me what that does?

Comment: Reads the entire hdf5 file into memory

Comment: Oh ok, this can't be in this case as the file is quite big (50gb)

Comment: There is no need to create a list to iterate over groups and datasets. You can iterate over the names/keys like this: `for timestamp in data.keys():` and `for players in data[timestamp].keys():`

Comment: @kcw78, oh, true. But I tried to do that and it didnt change performance :(

Comment: I suspect the performance issue has something to do with operations inside the "players" loop. What are you doing? I assume your code does more than print the elapsed time?

Comment: @kcw78, yes I suspected that as well. Indeed I do other things, but I tried to run the same loop just printing out the elapsed time and the problem still persists. It seems so that the issue is exactly on the access to data[timestamp].keys()

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's more going on than your your simple example captures. It should not show performance degradation when you are simply reading keys to get group and dataset names.

To demonstrate, I wrote an example that creates a file that mimics your schema. After it creates the file, it closes and reopens in read-only mode, then loops to access each timestamp group and player dataset and prints access time. Response time is consistently low for all timesteps. [Example file is 1.4 GB. Increase the size of `arr` if you want to test a larger file.] FYI, I ran this on a Windows system with 24 GB RAM.

Code below:

```
ntimes = 10000
nplayers = 10
hdf5file = 'SO_70466356.h5'
start_time = time.time()
with h5py.File(hdf5file, "w") as h5f:
    data = h5f.create_group('data')
    for t_cnt in range(ntimes):
        grp = data.create_group(f'time_{t_cnt:05}')
        for p_cnt in range(nplayers):
            arr = np.random.random(300*3).reshape(300,3)
            grp.create_dataset(f'player_{p_cnt:02}',data=arr)
print(f'HDF5 file creation time: {time.time()-start_time:.4f}')            

print(f'HDF5 file read times')            
with h5py.File(hdf5file, "r") as h5f:
    data = h5f['data']
    start_time = time.time()
    timestamps = list(data.keys())
    for cnt,timestamp in enumerate(timestamps):            
        players = list(data[timestamp].keys())
        if not (cnt+1)%1000 :
            print(f'For {timestamp}: {time.time()-start_time:.4f}')
            start_time = time.time()
```

Output from above:

```
HDF5 file creation time: 29.7558
HDF5 file read times
At time_00999: 0.1766
At time_01999: 0.1736
At time_02999: 0.1650
At time_03999: 0.1872
At time_04999: 0.1716
At time_05999: 0.1740
At time_06999: 0.1716
At time_07999: 0.1716
At time_08999: 0.1720
At time_09999: 0.1872
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Interestingly the same slow down occurs when I run your code! 
I set ntimes  = 10000 and nplayers = 10. And it took 249.13 for file creation. 
Some of the elapsed times:
For time_02699: 0.00008
For time_02799: 0.00008
For time_02899: 0.00049
For time_02999: 0.03894
For time_03099: 0.02930
For time_03199: 0.02993
For time_03299: 0.06007

Comment: Ah, and I changed if not (cnt+1)%1000 for if not (cnt+1)%100. 
I am running this on ubuntu on jupyterlab btw

Comment: Ok, I tried to run it outside of jupyterlab for some times. I noticed that the point where iterations start to be slow is basically the last iteration that runned in the previous time. So I guess that something is being cached, so iterations that were accessed before will be faster later.

Comment: I just realized I didn't include the lines with `ntimes` and `nplayers`. Sorry! Code updated to correct. I originally ran with `ntimes=20000` and `nplayers=10`. I modified to match your values and changed the time printout so it's the total over 1000 timestamps. Output added to my answer above. As you can see, time to read each 1000 timestamps are almost identical (range from 0.1650 to 0.1872 sec). Also, my time to create the file is much faster than yours. Clearly something is different in our 2 h/w or s/w configurations.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I ran this on a repl.it VM. (It only has 500MB RAM and 500MB storage, so I reduced to `ntimes=5000` and `nplayers=10`. Behavior was similar to my Windows W/S.  Time to read 500 timestamps only showed some variation, but didn't get slower (ranged from 0.1292 to 0.2180 sec and last 2 increments were both 0.1489 sec). So, it doesn't look like amount of RAM is an issue.